# Entity framework Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have entity `User` with a couple of `one-to-one` and `many-to-many` relations and `Identity primary key`, and `generic repository` which created on each request.

I have an registration form with client and server validation and i decided to turn off client validation to test how server would behave in such case.

I turned off client validation to test the registration form and put some invalid values so i get back form saying that i have some errors, after i fixed that i got very interesting error
saying:

```
_context.SaveChanges(); //towing the error below:

Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key
```

It was strange for me because i detached the entity `User` but when i found this [How to clean-up an Entity Framework object context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465933/how-to-clean-up-an-entity-framework-object-context)
so instead detaching only `User` entity i decided to try to clean object context completely running that code:

```
var objectStateEntries = this.objectContext
                             .ObjectStateManager
                             .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added);

    foreach (var objectStateEntry in objectStateEntries)
    {
        if(objectStateEntry.Entity != null)
           this.objectContext.Detach(objectStateEntry.Entity);
    }
```

So after that all working well and i didn't get `Conflicting changes detected` error any more, but i am still wondering why such situation was taking place, may be some one may explain?

Comment: Show how you're inserting `User`

Answer (score 0):

You may find your answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adodotnetentityframework/thread/b8b016c0-ec70-496f-b52d-c42e3ef7d6c0):

```
context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added| System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged);
```

Comment: Does this answer the question? He specifically asks why this was occurring in the first place, in that his code shouldn't be creating a degenerate state - not how to see what's valid and what isn't.